# For loop skipping over await sleep

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

I am having an issue where i have a function that should sleep for a designated time if data is not populated in an array, before moving on to the next iteration.

For whatever reason the sleep is getting skipped over and it just continues without sleeping.

```
const sleep = (millis) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve("done"), millis));

async function getBackupData(ID, Data) {
  const sleeptime = 60;
  const attempts = 10;
  let urlArray;

  for (let i = 0; i < attempts + 1; i += 1) {
    if (i === attempts) { throw new Error("Download URL not available"); }
    urlArray = await getDownloadUrls(ID, data);

    if (urlArray.length > 0) {
      break;
    }
    console.log(`${i} - Download url not available yet: sleeping ${sleeptime} seconds`);
    await sleep(sleeptime * 1000);
  }
  console.log(`returning ${urlArray[0]}`);
  return urlArray[0];
}
```

output:

```
0 - Download url not available yet: sleeping 60 seconds
1 - Download url not available yet: sleeping 60 seconds
2 - Download url not available yet: sleeping 60 seconds
3 - Download url not available yet: sleeping 60 seconds
4 - Download url not available yet: sleeping 60 seconds
5 - Download url not available yet: sleeping 60 seconds
6 - Download url not available yet: sleeping 60 seconds
7 - Download url not available yet: sleeping 60 seconds
8 - Download url not available yet: sleeping 60 seconds
9 - Download url not available yet: sleeping 60 seconds
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {
  <rejected> Error: Download URL not available
```

This should be sleeping for 60 seconds on each iteration but this takes only a few seconds to complete as is... Can someone please take a look to see what is going on?

Comment: it should be `(resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("done")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const sleep = (millis) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve("done"), millis));
```

calls `resolve("done")` immediately, and passes the result of the call `resolve("done")` as parameter to `setTimeout`.

You either pass the function `resolve` as parameter to `setTimeout`  (there is not real need to resolve with `done`):

```
const sleep = (millis) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
```

Or if you really want to resolve with `done` use an arrow function:

```
const sleep = (millis) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve("done"), millis));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i will mark this as the completed resolved answer

Comment: Is this any different from the solutions presented in the proposed duplicate?